# How to access user database with VueJs and Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, web-applications, firebase-realtime-database, vuejs2

I am trying to output the current authenticated username after the user has signed in with Firebase.

Currently in VueJs I am getting the `.currentUser` then accessing the `users` database. As seen in the screenshot I am trying to output the username that matches the current users UID inside the `/users/` database. The problem is that the log outputs null for `username`

```
getName: function () {
  var userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    return firebase.database().ref('/users/' + userId).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
  var username = (snapshot.val() && snapshot.val().username);
     console.log(username)
    })
},
```

[image: firebase_vuejs_username]

Comment: did you getting the correct `userId`?

Comment: @Hareesh yep, when logging `userId` I get the correct ID. It's the next step that is incorrect.

Comment: try `var username = snapshot.val().username`

Comment: try removing the extra `/` . Like this: `ref('users/' + userId)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
getName: function () {
   var userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
   return firebase.database().ref('/users/' + 
      userId).on('value', function(snapshot) {
         if (snapshot.val()) {
            var obj = snapshot.val();
            var userName = snapshot.val().username;
            console.log('username:', userName)
         }
   });
}
```

once method will call node only once but on will call everytime.

Comment: I receive the following error: `Error: Query.on failed: Was called with 1 argument. Expects at least 2.`

Comment: i changed my code,check once and let me know if you are facing any problem @scopeak

Comment: That worked thanks! Regarding using `.on` instead of `.once` should I not be using `once` if it's just for things like displaying a username that won't really change?

Comment: As per my knowledge on will be use whenever we want to fetch data. and once whenever node will update.